# Unable to return value from get method, using interpolation. not printing 'this._title' value from getTitle() method

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: '<h1>{{ getTitle() }}</h1>'  ////not printing 'this._title' value???
})

export class CoursesComponent{
    private _title: string;

    set Title(x: string){
        this._title = x;
    }

    getTitle(): string{                //method 
        return this._title;        
    }
}

let obj = new CoursesComponent;
obj.Title = 'List of Courses';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. No its not getting the value. Please help me on howto achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work that way. Use ngInit to initialize your component and values.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: '<h1>{{ getTitle() }}</h1>'  ////not printing 'this._title' value???
})

export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
    private _title: string;

    set Title(x: string){
        this._title = x;
    }

    getTitle(): string{                //method 
        return this._title;        
    }
    ngOnInit() { this.Title = 'List of Courses'; }
}
```

Angular creates the component in it's engine. Basically, when you add the component in an html file, angular knows which class to use, runs the constructor and if it implements on init, it will execute it.

In your code, you created a component that was never used by angular. You did set the title, but the component was never added to any view.

Comment: Hi Kataras, Yes its working :). Thank you so much for your solution.
But may i know why it is not working with the object? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @ShyamPrasad, in your first code you don't give value to this._title, do you want to say `getTitle(){return this.obj.Title}`?